# Fabric.js: How to turn SVG loaded from URL into grayscale?

Tags: canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm working on a customization tool for products where users can upload their SVG files so they can be printed on products.

Now, I need to be able to turn this imported logo in grayscale to show them how it would look if they choose the laser print type.

I know there is a Grayscale filter which would do just that but it doesn't seem to work on my element loaded with this code (don't mind the {$var} which are from smarty) :

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(r.filepath, function(objects, options){

        var loadedObjects = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

        //loadedObjects.setCoords();

        //loadedObjects.setCoords();
        var scaleX = canvas_{$image.id_image}.width / loadedObjects.width;
        var scaleY =  canvas_{$image.id_image}.height / loadedObjects.height;
        var scale = (scaleX > scaleY) ? scaleY : scaleX;

        canvas_{$image.id_image}.add(loadedObjects).renderAll();
        loadedObjects.setCoords();
        loadedObjects.set({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            scaleX: scale,
            scaleY: scale,
            selectable: true
        });

        loadedSVG_{$image.id_image} = loadedObjects;

        canvas_{$image.id_image}.renderAll();

    });
```

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this result. Should I turn my element into an `fabric.Image` ? Wouldn't that impact the resizing capabilities by destroying the vectors ?

Is there another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do load your svg as an image using `Fabric.Image.fromURL()` directly, your svg image won't loose quality, since the `<img>` tag used to *store* the svg image is still in vectors.

But, when applying an Image Filter, the filter is applied once, on a `<canvas>` element, at the default size of your img tag which results in a rasterization of your image.

One hackish way to do it would have been to load the svg in an object or iframe or embed tag first, append the desired filter as an SVGFilter, then load the svg from the DOM string into Fabric.

But this has some limitations :

- cross origin request are blocked, and there is no `crossOrigin` attribute on these tags.
- You have to do the parsing yourself.
- There seems to be a bug in FF with the image box when upscaled...

Anyway, here is the code and [a plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9dSrGuP9XLXgxQRUDYm?p=preview) to show it live.

```js
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

   var obj = document.createElement('object');
    //make it invisible
   obj.style.height = obj.style.width = 0;
    // we have to append it so it does load
   document.body.appendChild(obj);

   obj.onload = function() {
     // get the def node of our svgFilter
     var defs = document.getElementById('def').cloneNode('true');
     // get the doc of our object
     var doc = obj.contentDocument || obj.contentWindow.documentElement;
     // we can now remove the <object>
     document.body.removeChild(obj);
     // the target svg
     var svg = doc.querySelector('svg');
     svg.insertBefore(defs, svg.firstElementChild);
     // set the filter on the whole svg
     svg.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#desaturate)');
     // encode it to a dataURI
     var svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
     var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgStr);
     // load it as an image
     fabric.Image.fromURL(svgURL, function(img) {
       canvas.add(img).renderAll();
     });

     // We could have tried with loadSVGFrom... but the filter isn't applied then
     /*
     fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr, function(objects, options) {
       var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
       canvas.add(loadedObject);
       loadedObject.center().setCoords();
       canvas.renderAll();
     });
     fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgURL, function(objects, options) {
       var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
       canvas.add(loadedObject);
       loadedObject.center().setCoords();
       canvas.renderAll();
     });
     */
   };
   obj.data = "yourFile.svg";
```

```html
<!-- append your svg filter in the main doc -->
<svg id="filters" width="0" height="0">
  <defs id="def">
    <filter id="desaturate">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0      0      0      1 0" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

---

An other solution would have been to first draw your svg on an up-scaled canvas, apply the filter on its dataURL, then downscale the image, but this will create some compression artifacts too...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var scaleSVG = function(url, scale, callback) {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    c.width = this.width * scale;
    c.height = this.height * scale;
    c.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    callback(c.toDataURL());
  };
  img.src = url;
};

scaleSVG('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b7qcju9ubmdtigj/ball.svg',
  10, function(dataURL) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(dataURL, function(img) {
      // scale in the other side
      var oImg = img.scale(.1);
      var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
      oImg.filters.push(filter);
      canvas.add(oImg);
      oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    }, {
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    });
  });
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first solution worked well, the second one gets the same compression problem as `.cloneAsImage`. Anyways, thank you so much for your answer I would never have thought of doing this!